# Piping Readable to Writable leads to crash

Tags: node.js, crash, node.js-stream

I have a Readable that generates an infinite sequence:

```
var stream = require('stream');
var readable = new stream.Readable({
  read: function (size) {
    for (;;) {
      var s = ' ' + (++this.count);
      if (!readable.push(s))
        break;
    }
  }
});
readable.count = 0;
readable.pipe(process.stdout);
```

It can run forever, as expected:

```
.... 4151609 4151610 4151611 4151612 ....
```

And I also have a Writable that eats up anything given to it:

```
var writable = new stream.Writable({
  write: function (chunk, encoding, next) {
    console.log('w: ' + (++this.count));
    next();
  }
});
writable.count = 0;
process.stdin.pipe(writable);
```

I tested it with a very large file and it works as expected, too:

```
$ cat very-large-file | node test.js
....
w: 306772
w: 306773
w: 306774
w: 306775
....
```

However, when I pipe `readable` to `writable`:

```
readable.pipe(writable);
```

the program runs for a while, then crashes with a core dump:

```
w: 118351
w: 118352
w: 118353
<--- Last few GCs --->

  215645 ms: Scavenge 1398.2 (1457.3) -> 1398.2 (1457.3) MB, 0.4 / 0 ms (+ 0.9 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
  216771 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.2 (1457.3) -> 1387.4 (1457.3) MB, 1125.9 / 0 ms (+ 0.9 ms in 1 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.9 ms) [last resort gc].
  217877 ms: Mark-sweep 1387.4 (1457.3) -> 1396.9 (1457.3) MB, 1105.9 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x1b8ff3b4629 <JS Object>
    1: nextTick [node.js:~477] [pc=0x5e5d1d9bd7b] (this=0xf61bdf1c521 <a process with map 0x53539c10f99>,callback=0xf0666bf7411 <JS Function afterWrite (SharedFunctionInfo 0xf0666b1ae01)>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 5->1
    3: onwrite(aka onwrite) [_stream_writable.js:~314] [pc=0x5e5d1d83f5e] (this=0x1b8ff3041b9 <undefined>,stream=0xf0666bf7961 <a Writable with map 0x178127921271>,er=0x1b8...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Why? Am I doing anything wrong?

## Update

ShanShan commented that the writable is slowed by the console.log and can't follow all the input from the readable, thus the out of memory crash. To test this theory, I did an experiment:

```
var stream = require('stream');
var readable = new stream.Readable({
  highWaterMark: 20,
  read: function (size) {
    for (;;) {
      var s = ' ' + (++this.count);
      if (!readable.push(s))
        break;
    }
    console.log('r: ' + this.count + ' - ' + this._readableState.buffer.length);
  }
});
readable.count = 0;
var writable = new stream.Writable({
  write: function (chunk, encoding, next) {
    console.log('w: ' + (++this.count));
    next();
  }
});
writable.count = 0;
readable.pipe(writable);
```

The code is almost the same as before, except that:

1. I set the highWaterMark (buffer size limit) to a very low value;
2. I added a console.log to the readable.

The output follows:

```
r: 10 - 10
r: 11 - 11
w: 1
w: 2
r: 12 - 10
w: 3
r: 13 - 10
w: 4
w: 5
r: 14 - 9
w: 6
r: 15 - 9
w: 7
w: 8
r: 16 - 8
w: 9
r: 17 - 8
w: 10
r: 18 - 8
w: 11
r: 19 - 8
w: 12
....
r: 20564 - 5
w: 20560
r: 20565 - 5
w: 20561
r: 20566 - 5
w: 20562
r: 20567 - 5
w: 20563
r: 20568 - 5
w: 20564
```

And the program still crashed. Apparently, the execution of `readable` and `writable` is almostly strictly interleaved, and the buffer size is always small, so I don't think ShanShan's theory is correct.

Comment: *process out of memory* is pretty explicit, the writable is slowed by the console.log and can't follow all the input from the readable. The data is queued and take more and more memory until the process is out of memory.

Comment: That should be a memory leak somewhere in the loop. Which node version are you using and what documentation do you follow?

Comment: @ShanShan: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately my experiment shows that your theory is incorrect. Please see my edit.

Comment: @eljefedelrodeodeljefe: I'm using v4.3.0, and following the same version of documentation. After seeing your comment, I also tried v5.5.0, and got the same crash. Then I tried v0.12, too, but unfortunately my program could not run on it.